# Pass data through views Xcode 4.2 storyboarding

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistoryboard

My project is basically a performance car application, using `arc4rand()` to determine which car will show up next.
I have made a [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6hj1.jpg) to explain what I need it to do.

my .h code

```
 @interface BMW : UIViewController {

  IBOutlet UIImageView *view;

  IBOutlet UILabel *label;

}

-(IBAction)random;

@end
```

my .m code

```
-(IBAction)random {
   int image = arc4random() % 1;
   switch (image) {
   case 0:
       block.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"m3.jpg"];
       label.text = @"BMW m3" ;
       break;

   default:
       break;
  }
```

how can i get the label and picture to carry over to the 2nd view?
I am using Xcode 4.2.1 and storyboarding

Answer (score 1):

One possibility: Make the label and picture ivars in the 2nd view controller and set them like this 
in `newController.h`

```
@interface newController : UIViewController 
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *labelText;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UILabel *label;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImage *image;
@end
```

in `newController.m`

```
@implementation newController 
@synthesize labelText, image, label;

- (void)viewWillAppear
{
   label.text = labelText;
}
@end
```

Set the identifier of the segue in IB/Xcode to `pushNewViewController` and add the prepareForSegue in your code:

```
#import "NewController.h"
...
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"pushNewController"]) {
        [segue.destinationViewController setLabelText:label.text];
        [segue.destinationViewController setImage:block.image];
    }
}
```

If you want to learn more about `UIViewControllers` and storyboards I recomment you to see the current [Stanford CS 193P](http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewPodcast?id=473757255) course which works fully with iOS 5

Comment: Would be correct except the question is using storyboards, so your last piece of code should be in the prepareForSegue method and you'd get the new view controller from segue.destinationViewController

Comment: Oh, and also the label wouldnt exist at that point as the view isn't loaded, so you'd have to pass a string and populate the label in viewWillAppear (annoying!)

Comment: @jrturton your are right with the prepareForSegue - just got up ;) - so changed the code. Are you sure that you cannot set the label text?

Comment: Pretty sure, I remember having to change it around. The object has been created but the view hasn't loaded yet, so the items from the nib are all nil. It seemed the wrong way around to me at the time for exactly this reason.

Comment: I tried this and could not get it to work! Do I have to set the new view to a custom class -> NewController ?

And the prepareForSegue part, what file does that go into? 
Thanks

Comment: yes you have to make them a special class. you need the .h and .h vie New File and put the newController stuff inside. You'll also need to adjust the viewcontroller in IB to you new custom class. The prepareForSegue part is in the view controller which creates and calls the new vc which is your current vc. i really recommend the iTunes U course. It's free and you'll learn a lot!

Comment: I will definitely take a look at those. I should have all the codes in the right files and I set the segues to the correct classes.  But the referencing outlets for my 2nd view do not match my first, maybe thats the problem?

Comment: @Pfitz - I have just found out that if you access the .view property of the destination view controller in prepareForSegue (e.g wrap everything in `if (destinationVC.view)` or similar) then this forces the view to load and you _can_ directly access the labels etc. sorry for misinforming you.

Comment: hey again, i got that code to work but it's not exactly doing what i wanted. all it's doing is carrying over the same functionality to the 2nd view. what i need it to do is carry the information randomly generated on the first view and display it on the 2nd